# How to prevent users from deleting pre-populated values in Gravity Forms?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Is there any specific way to prevent users from deleting pre-populated values in Gravity Forms?
I wish to append a static country code in the phone field but still allow the full phone number to be filled by the end user.

Thanks!

Comment: no either add it as an overlay / placeholder (by padding the original input to make space for the prefix code) or use javascript to prepend the code before submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a perfect solution, but it might work for you.

1. Add a Single Line Text field to your form.
2. Enable the "Input Mask" setting.
3. Set the mask to "Custom" and enter a custom mask ([example](http://grab.by/Mklo)).

Any number besides "9" will appear as a "static" value when the user selects the field. Then use "9" to indicate a digit the user would enter themselves. Here is what my example in Step 3 would look like on the frontend ([screenshot](http://grab.by/Mkls)).

Comment: Thanks this worked but how can I make digit 9 as a static?

Comment: You'd need to define a custom placeholder for numeric digits. More info here: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/